# SAS CATS() function is stripping leading zeroes of numeric variables?

Tags: sas, concatenation

I have two columns of numeric variables that I am trying to combine using the CATS function in SAS. However, SAS is stripping the leading zeroes of my variables, which I need, see example below.

```
var1=01
var2=001
result = cats(var1, var2)
```

And the printed result is 11. How do I get the result to be 01001? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing value and format.  In your program SAS converts var1 and var2 to character using best format.

```
24         data _null_;
25            var1=01;
26            var2=001;
27            result = catx('-',vvalue(var1), vvalue(var2));
28            format var1 z2. var2 z3.;
29            put _all_;
30            run;

var1=01 var2=001 result=01-001 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
```

Comment: That worked. I had been setting the format before the cats statement so what I needed was the vvalue function.

Comment: You're saying you didn't actually show your program.  That would have been helpful.  In short SAS does not convert to character in CAT family of functions using the associated format it uses best12. I think.